# Extjs Grid - selected row without influence to checkboxmodel

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

i using CheckboxModel like

```
,selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        mode: 'MULTI',
        checkOnly: true
}
```

I want When i click a row and it will be selected. I using

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex, true);
```

But that row also turn on Checkbox at the same time.

I want selected row and it don't influence to checkboxmodel thanks

Answer (score 1):

CheckboxModel's purpose is row selection.  The functionality you actually want is provided by the `Ext.ux.CheckColumn`.  See the docs at: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.CheckColumn

Comment: i using CheckboxModel because it has check all. Any idea?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393660/extjs-4-select-multiple-checkcolumn-checkboxes-with-checkbox-header/11440809#11440809

Comment: it look complex for me to understand :(